# Composition of two matrix transformations

Tags: matrices, transformation, function-and-relation-composition

Consider two matrices acting on points in $(0,1)^2$ in the real plane, $$h_s=\begin{pmatrix}   e^{-e^{s}} & 0 \\   0 & e^{-e^{-s}}   \end{pmatrix}.$$

and $$g_s=\begin{pmatrix}   1-e^{-e^{s}} & 0 \\   0 & e^{-e^{-s}}   \end{pmatrix}.$$

> How do you compose these transformations?

I tried to do $h_s \circ g_s$ but got stuck because I haven't dealt with composition of matrices before.

I have done function composition, so I am familiar with that concept.

Comment: treat a point as a 2-by-1 vector.  a 2-by-2 matrix acts on it by left multiiplication

Comment: could you make an answer @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat a point $(x,y)$ as a $2 \times 1$ vector $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$.  You may want to start with usual calculations for function compositions

\begin{align}
g_s \left( \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right)
&= \begin{pmatrix} 1-e^{-e^{s}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-e^{-s}} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} (1-e^{-e^{s}})x \\ e^{-e^{-s}}y \end{pmatrix}. \tag{1} \label{my1} \\
(h_s \circ g_s) \left( \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right)
&= h_s\left( g_s\left( \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right) \right) \\
&= h_s\left( \begin{pmatrix} (1-e^{-e^{s}})x \\ e^{-e^{-s}}y \end{pmatrix} \right) \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} e^{-e^{s}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-e^{-s}} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} (1-e^{-e^{s}})x \\ e^{-e^{-s}}y \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} e^{-e^{s}} (1-e^{-e^{s}})x \\ e^{-2e^{-s}}y \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

From this, it's clear that $h_s \circ g_s = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-e^{s}}(1-e^{-e^{s}}) & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-2e^{-s}} \end{pmatrix}$.

However, it's preferable to describe $g_s$ and $h_s$ in words.  In this way, you see this directly without writing the vector.  Note that in a matrix product, the row $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ on the left means to "pick the first row in the matrix/vector on its right-hand side".  It's easy to see why the first row of the right-hand side in \eqref{my1} is $(1-e^{-e^s})x$.  The second row follows similarly.

With this verbal description of matrix product in mind, you can find the matrix product
$$ \begin{pmatrix} e^{-e^{s}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-e^{-s}} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1-e^{-e^{s}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-e^{-s}} \end{pmatrix} $$
using the matrices associated with $h_s$ and $g_s$.  Note that the question asks for $h_s \circ g_s$, so you have to put
$$\text{matrix for } h_s \cdot \text{matrix for } g_s.$$
Note that the matrices in this question are diagonal matrices, so you can simply do an element-by-element multiplication on the diagonal.